# sampling from the set of indixes using python/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability

I have a 4 indexes {1,2,3,4} and I want to associate a probability of co-occurrence for index 1 and index 2 as 0.8 and probability of co-occurrence of index 3 and 4 as 0.7 and probability of co-occurrence of index 1 and 3 as 0.1 and probability of co-occurrence of index 2 and 4 as 0.1.

How can I sample 100 instances such that I get tuples of indexes distributed according to the above density ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
>>> indices = np.transpose(np.triu_indices(4)) + 1
>>> probs = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1])
>>> pairs = indices[np.random.choice(np.arange(10), 1000000, p=probs/probs.sum())]
```

Note that I created a few more pairs in order to get better statistics:

```
>>> np.mean((pairs[(pairs == 1).any(1)] == 2).any(1))
0.8011017893563784
>>> np.mean((pairs[(pairs == 3).any(1)] == 4).any(1))
0.7013376446633661
>>> np.mean((pairs[(pairs == 1).any(1)] == 3).any(1))
0.09918417123993356
>>> np.mean((pairs[(pairs == 2).any(1)] == 4).any(1))
0.09942011933775947
```

Comment: interesting. what is the idea behind it ?

Comment: @Shew It's just brute forcing it. `indices` is a list of all possible (ordered) pairs. `probs` are the probabilities you prescribe. Note that there are a few degrees of freedom left here. For example, I think you could have made the (1, 4) and (2, 3) probs smaller and compensated for that by making the (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4) probs larger. Anyway, we then use the probs to draw indices (numpy refused to draw pairs directly) and use advanced indexing to get the corresponding pairs.